# Nodejs adding extra backslash(\) in string

Tags: node.js, regex, escaping, regexp-replace

I am trying this sample code

```js
let route = {
                paths: []
            }
            
let convertedStr0 = "/{test}/search/v1/{userId}"

let convertedStr1 = convertedStr0.replace(new RegExp("{", 'g'), "(?<").replace(new RegExp("}", 'g'), ">\\S+)$");

console.log(convertedStr1);  //Output: /(?<test>\S+)$/search/v1/(?<userId>\S+)$

route.paths[0] = convertedStr1;
console.log(route); //Output: { paths: [ '/(?<test>\\S+)$/search/v1/(?<userId>\\S+)$' ] }
```

I need to write the route result in a file with single backslash (`\`). But an extra backslash is appended. Any one has any suggestion how I can fix this issue?

Comment: Hello and welcome on StackOverflow. Could you please provide a **reproducible** example?

Comment: I have already provided the code example. 
convertedStr1 output is good like
/(?<test>\S+)$/search/v1/(?<userId>\S+)$

but i just assign the string to route object and resut becomes
/(?<test>\\S+)$/search/v1/(?<userId>\\S+)$

\\S is apended now

Comment: Sorry, for some reason I thought there was missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to keep the single backslash in the output file, first [stringify](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_stringify.asp) your `route` object and then replace the double slash with a single one:

```
route = JSON.stringify(route, null, 2)
            .replaceAll("\\\\","\\");
console.log(route); //Output: { "paths": [ "/(?<test>\S+)$/search/v1/(?<userId>\S+)$" ] }
```

Answer (score 1):

The backslash is also an escaping Character. In your literally string, `">\\S+)$"`, the 1st escaping the 2nd. this means both `"\\"` defining single literally char of `\`.

In the 1st console.log, your output is a sequence of characters. In character terms you have only single backslash defined in your string.

In the 2nd console.log, your output is a string representation of your sequence. So there is doubled backslash, representing one escaping the another.

Notice also, that the 1st output is not wrapped with single quotes as in the 2nd case.

Comment: My issue is when I write the route object to a file then in file "\\" is written in file instead of "\". It is important for me to have '\' in file. How I can fix it ?